# Getting an error when trying to download an image

Tags: swift, nsurlsession, nsurlsessiondatatask

I am trying to download an image using the following code:

```
 if let imageUrl = post.postImageURL{
        let url = NSURL(string: imageUrl)
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
            if error != nil{
                print(error)
                return
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                cell.itemImage.image = UIImage(data: data)
            }

        }).resume()
    }
```

When I try to build it, I get the following error message:

```
Ambiguous reference to member 'dataTask(with:completionHandler:)'
```

How can I fix this error?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API expects Swift `URL` struct, not Foundation `NSURL` class.

Just remove `NS`

```
let url = URL(string: imageUrl)
```

Basically don't use Foundation `NS..` classes if there is a native Swift counterpart.